# Is this checksum calculation completely waterproof?

Tags: bit-manipulation, checksum

```
long make_checksum(const char* str)
{
  long chk=0;
  long rot=0;
  while(*str)
  {
    rot<<=9;
    rot|=(rot>>23);
    rot^=*(char*)str++;
    chk+=rot;
  }
  return chk;
}
```

***Not waterproof means: there's a chance I can get the same checksum for two different strings.***

Comment: The questions you want to ask are, "are the checksum values evenly distributed across all possible strings", and "if I have one randoml chosen string, and another string identical to the first except for a very small number of changes, will I statistically get two different checksums values so I can tell the good one from the erroneous one?". Other people have solved this problem and use complicated mathematics to get it right. Use one of thier solutions. CRC32 (or CRC64) is extremely good for this; so are many other "hash" functions. There's usually one easily found in your runtime libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there are more possible strings than long values, there are surely two different strings resulting in the same checksum.

Answer (score 1):

A checksum can never be waterproof, since it contains less data than the original data of which you are calculating the checksum.

If you want a real waterproof 'checksum', you need to create a second 'instance' of your data and make sure that it contains identically the same data as the original data, although it does not have to be in the same format (can be encryped or compressed).